# Display description on cart page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to display main product description on the cart page? I tried this but it works only for variation description.

```
$_product->description
```

I want to display the main description which is the same for all variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_product object is product variation object.

You have to first get the parent product id and then get the description of parent product.

```
$parent_product_id =$_product->get_parent_id();
$parent_product = get_post($parent_product_id);
echo $content = $parent_product->post_content;
```

Or

```
 echo $_product->parent->description;
```